# What to do about "caesar" and "julius-caesar" that currently mean the same person?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just noticed that there are two tags for the same person, [caesar](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/caesar) and [julius-caesar](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/julius-caesar).

Here are the links: [caesar](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/caesar) and [julius-caesar](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/julius-caesar).

[julius-caesar](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/julius-caesar) has no uage guidance, but [caesar](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/caesar) has:

> Questions relating to the Roman politician and general Gaius Julius Caesar

This also makes clear that it's about the person, not the [title](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_(title)).

I suggest to have only one tag for the person, [julius-caesar](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/julius-caesar).

**Can we merge** [caesar](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/caesar) **and** [julius-caesar](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/julius-caesar)**?**

We could also decide to turn [caesar](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/caesar) into a tag for the title, not the person. Then the usage guidance would have to be changed. That's indeed possible, see the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70718):

> Merging, by itself, does not create a synonym, meaning that the tag that was merged can be recreated and used later.

**Should** [caesar](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/caesar) **be used only when it's about the title?**

I found 4 question for which that is appropriate:

- [Is this true that the requirement to sacrifice to the Roman gods was put in by the Caesar only after Christianity emerged?](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/3208/38309)
- [Is there any Historical Evidence for a Co-Regency of Tiberius and Augustus?](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/37567/38309)
- [Tiberius, Augustus, and Eusebius](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/37790/38309)
- [Did any ancient historian consider Tiberius' first year as Emperor to be the first year of his co-regency with Augustus?](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/37753/38309)

With only 14 questions tagged [caesar](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/caesar) you may decide that retagging by hand and changing the usage guidance of [caesar](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/caesar) only, would suffice. This is mainly about clearing up the confusion.

Answer (score 10):

I take a different view here. I have just searched the [caesar](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/caesar) tag, and found questions relating both to Julius Caesar **and** to the title/other emperors. Personally, I would prefer [julius-caesar](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/julius-caesar) to be person-specific, and [caesar](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/caesar)  to be more general, covering the next c.400 years.

"**Render to Caesar the things that are Caesar's.**"

Comment: Just to pump this argument a bit, its pretty clear than no less that 4 posters wanted a caesar tag so badly, that they *went against the clear advice of the tag wiki* and used it that way. We don't know how many more would have used it that way, if the wiki actually supported that usage.

Comment: @T.E.D True. As see it, Caesar was simply a family name, and is used as such in "Julius Caesar". It became a **title** by extension/identification only later. In the present context, the tag [tag:caesar] would make no sense when saying "Christians refused to make sacrifices to Caesar.", since ***Julius Caesar*** was dead before the rise of Christianity. I find the current tags illogical.

Comment: Has this been resolved, or do we still have [tag:caesar] and  [tag:julius-caesar] tags?

Comment: @TheHonRose I resolved it today by redefining the caesar tag as suggested in your answer.

Comment: @called2voyage Thank you, seems logical to me!

Answer (score 9):

So I basically see two questions here:

1. Is it useful to have a separate tag for rulers with "Ceasar" in their name/title?

I could see arguments on both sides of this. People used it that way 4 times (despite the tag wiki). Perhaps it might even be worthwhile to have something that somehow includes later titles derived from "Ceasar" (eg: Tsar, Keiser). However, I think I'm currently leaning toward a "no" on this one. Perhaps if we need something like "Emperor", that can be discussed separately.

2. What should we do about the two existing tags that are clearly intended to apply to the same concept?

On this one, I'd be inclined to get rid of [ceasar](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ceasar) in favor of [julius-ceasar](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/julius-ceasar) (but with the former's wiki info), as the latter makes it clearer what it applies to, and already includes the text of the former for easy searching.

Different answers encouraged, if anyone feels differently.

Comment: My question was originally only about Julius, when it occurred to me that "caesar" could also mean the title. 4 questions are not that much. I guess "roman-empire" already covers that, too (in contrast to "roman-kingdom" and "roman-republic", tags that already exist). 3 of the 4 questions also have the tag "roman-empire", but not [this one](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/3208/38309) - adding that tag might make sense there.

Comment: The 4 Qs needed re-tagging (to follow wiki wiki), without checking, we seem to not have a [caesar] (title) tag needed. But as that might change, it's best to keep that one clean for future use. Re-iterating, imo we do not need a caesar tag *now*.